# Docker setup for a development environment?

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to find out how to setup my current docker compose yaml file to run my dev env. I'm new to docker but I was given a project that uses it.

```
version: '3'
 services:
  database:
    image: someinfo:9.5
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pass
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  backend:
    build: .
    command: bash /somepath/server/django_devserver.sh
    volumes:
    - .:/volumeinfo
    links:
    - database
    ports:
    - "8000:8000"
    environment:
      DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: projectname.settings.production
      SCHEMA: https
      DB_HOST: database
      PYTHONUNBUFFERED: 1
 volumes:
  db-data:
```

Currently this is running the Django production settings in my dev env. I want to keep that there but I also want to tell docker to run my dev settings when in the dev server. How can I do that? Would I create a new container called dev-backend with the dev vars?

Then would I run `docker-compose up dev-backend` or something like that? Forgive my ignorance, today is my first day with Docker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to create a separate compose file for your development environment. A good start would be to copy this file and change the appropriate settings (such as `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`).

By default, `docker-compose` searches for a file called `docker-compose.yml` and uses it to bring up the containers; but you can pass in a custom file name with `-f`.

```
[~]$ docker-compose -f dev.yml up
```

`dev.yml` is the name of your development settings file. It can be called anything, as long as its proper YAML.

It would be good to bookmark the [compose file reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/) from the documentation, as there is a very comprehensive list of directives and options you can add here.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you try out the officially encouraged approach of [Docker Compose configuration overriding](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#adding-and-overriding-configuration):

```
# your_config.dev.yml

version: '3'

 services:
  database:
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=dev_user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=dev_pass

  backend:
    environment:
      DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: projectname.settings.development
      # ...
```

And this is how you override your production environment configuration with the one set for development:

`docker-compose -f your_config.yml -f your_config.dev.yml (build|up|...)`

*N.B. This is assuming `your_config.yml` is the one presented in the question.*